# LinuxのRの日本語対応

Tags: linux, r

LinuxのR（R言語）でPDFファイルを作成しています。

```
pdf(outfile)
plot(式)
dev.off()
```

日本語が含まれる場合は文字化けを起こしてしまいます。

R言語のLinux版の日本語対応版もしくは日本語パッチがあるのでしょうか？

アドバイスなどいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu16 (rocker/tidyverse のdocker イメージ)ですが、
"noto sans cjk"をインストールすれば行けました。

```
# bash から (rstudio ユーザーをsudoerに追加後)
sudo apt install fonts-noto-cjk
```

```
# Rにて
par(family="Noto Sans")
# theme()を使うと調整がラクです
ggplot()
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

当方環境は `CentOS 6.5`, `R version 3.1.2`

```
pdf(outfile, family="Japan1")
plot(式)
dev.off()
```

これでいかがでしょうか？
日本語が表示できるフォントを指定しないと文字化けを起こしてしまうはずですので、pdf() で日本語フォントを設定します。

---

※追記
[RjpWikiの質問コーナー](http://www.okada.jp.org/RWiki/?%BD%E9%B5%E9%A3%D1%A1%F5%A3%C1%20%A5%A2%A1%BC%A5%AB%A5%A4%A5%D6%286%29#u306453e)にて同様の現象に遭われた方がおりました。
以下にこちらでの検証に使用したコードを引用しておきますのでご確認ください。

```
d <- c(0:100)
v1 <- 10000 * exp(-0.05*d)

pdf(file="c:/test.pdf") 

plot (d,v1,xlab="時間", ylab="価値", 
main="", sub="指数関数", pch=22, 
ylim=c(0, 10000), type="l", lwd=2)

dev.off()
```

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。
やはりうまくいきません。
Os周りの設定が必要なんでしょうか？？
ちなみにOSはCentOS6.4です。

Comment: その CentOS には日本語フォントがインストールされていますか？
Cent のコマンドで `fc-match :lang=ja` を実行してみてください。ここで表示されたフォントを R のほうで指定してあげるとどうでしょうか？

Comment: # fc-match :lang=jaを実行すると
VL-PGothic-Regular.ttf: "VL PGothic" "regular"
と返ってきましたので
Rコンソールにて
pdf(outfile,family="VL PGothic")
を実行すると
  unknown family 'VL PGothic'
となってしましました

Comment: @WESUEK CentOS6.5、R 3.1.2 で実行したところ、正常に日本語が出力されました。
手元にあるこの環境は、`$ sudo yum  groupinstall "Japanese Support"` を導入しており、更に日本語フォントなどが使える状態になっています。この違いが影響を与えているのではと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

/etc/sysconfig/i18nがSentOS6のデフォルト設定では

```
LANG="C"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

となっているところを

```
#LANG="C"
LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

と変えたら変化ないでしょうか。